# Got an Ng0901 error when using routerLink

Tags: angular, ionic4

This week i ran into the NG0901 Error (Yeah no message than this error)
I don't know why because as it seems it's due to a RouterLink that is not correctly functionning.

To sum up the application, it's an order manager for bakery. All it was remaining is the parameter page to modify add or delete client, warehouse etc etc.

So i create a first page witch is call params and this page have button with routerLink element to 4 other page.

Here is my html code of the params page:

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>P.I.C 2.0 - Paramétre</ion-title>
    <ion-back-button slot="start" color="primary" defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><ion-button> <a routerLink="params-client">Client</a></ion-button></td>
      <td><ion-button routerLink="./params_depot">Depot</ion-button></td>
      <!--<td><ion-button  routerLink="../depot">Feuille depot</ion-button></td>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><ion-button routerLink="params-boul">Produit Boulangerie</ion-button></td>
      <td><ion-button routerLink="params_pat">Produit Patisserie</ion-button></td>
      <!--<td><ion-button routerLink="../params">Paramètre</ion-button></td>-->
    </tr>
  </table>
</ion-content>
```

And to this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1US97vGf5BWp3mq80B563m4cBdO2AOVlq/view?usp=sharing) is the behavior that is unusual of the ion-button and routerLink

Also here is my ng --version

[ng --version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFWSR.png)

Here is also the StackTrace :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0901
Error: NG0901
    at e.find (main.js:1:604380)
    at C.ngDoCheck (main.js:1:468239)
    at Xa (main.js:1:501521)
    at cs (main.js:1:501322)
    at xi (main.js:1:501042)
    at $i (main.js:1:524323)
    at sy (main.js:1:531388)
    at Vv (main.js:1:525062)
    at $i (main.js:1:525073)
    at Hv (main.js:1:525433)
    at fe (polyfills.js:1:137971)
    at fe (polyfills.js:1:137482)
    at polyfills.js:1:138833
    at S.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1:128604)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1:583005)
    at S.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1:128525)
    at S.runTask (polyfills.js:1:123644)
    at P (polyfills.js:1:130949)
    at S.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.js:1:129774)
    at x (polyfills.js:1:142703)
zm @ main.js:1
```

And i also add the typescript and the html page where the routerLink is pointing at:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpRequestService} from "../../http-request.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-params-client',
  templateUrl: './params-client.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./params-client.page.scss'],
})
export class ParamsClientPage implements OnInit {
  public client:any = {}
  constructor(private http: HttpRequestService) {
    this.http.get_client_all((data) => {
      this.client = data;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}



<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>P.I.C 2.0 - Parémetre Client </ion-title>
    <ion-back-button slot="start" color="primary" defaultHref="params" ></ion-back-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>Id</ion-col>
    <ion-col>Nom</ion-col>
    <ion-col>Lieu</ion-col>
    <ion-col>Téléphone</ion-col>
    <ion-col>Modifier</ion-col>
    <ion-col>Supprimer</ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row *ngFor="let c of client">
    <ion-col>{{c.id_client}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col>{{c.name}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col>{{c.lieu}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col>{{c.tel}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-button>Modifier</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-button>Supprimer</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-grid>


</ion-content>
```

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be because of `routerLink` and the link shared in the question doesn't show the error message. Can you please share the error stack trace?

Comment: I just edit my post hope you will find something

Comment: `this.client = data;`  here what's the structure of the value within  `data`?

Comment: It's normally an array of JSON object's. I double checked and it is

Comment: Thanks to you i just saw that i was declaring my client object as a JSON object and assigned to it an array. That was my problem. Thank you very much it now works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be because of below property initialization code:

```ts
public client:any = {}
```

`client` is defined as an object and not an array and hence you will get an error during `*ngFor="let c of client"`.

NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. If you expect `data` received from the HTTP call to be an array, then you should **not** initialize `client` with empty object `{}`. Either you can assign `[]` or have no assignment at all.

If `client` is truly an object, then you should use [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) to iterate over an object.

> Transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.